# Is there a downside to using [true, 'true'].includes(someVariable) to check if a value is true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In our system we can not always be sure if a parameter was given as String or as a Boolean value (dynamic typing ahoi!), therefor, if e.g. we want to check if a certain flag was passed as true (so either boolean true or string 'true'), we usually check it using one of these options:

```
if (condition + '' === 'true')
```

which I don't like because of the implicit typecast

```
if ({true: true, 'true': true}[condition])
```

which I don't like because it's rather complex to read.

```
if (condition === true || condition === 'true')
```

which looks somewhat ugly to me and has an old feel to it.

Therefor, since **I want to consider all options** : is there a downside to using this variant:

```
[true, 'true'].includes(someVariable)
```

(Besides it being sort of a yoda-condition)

**Edit**: For completion, here are even more ways to check what I want to do:

```
if (condition.toString() === 'true')

if (String(condition) === 'true')
```

I think I'll stick with regular === 'true' || === true, checks, but it I'd still like to have my original question answered if possible.

Comment: why not `typeof`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: `if (condition === true || condition === 'true')` this is the clearest one.

Comment: @GrafiCode how?

Comment: I'd argue that `String(condition) === "true"` is way easier.

Comment: as per referenced link: `console.log(typeof true); // expected output: "boolean"`

Comment: @GrafiCode yes, but that's not what they're asking.

Comment: ok, I misread this `therefor, if e.g. we want to check if a certain flag was passed as true (so either boolean true or string 'true')`

Comment: Although I'm not sure why you can't just ensure that an argument is boolean when it is passed in. Sure, it's a bit harder, as you have to track down all *calling* places and modify them instead of just modifying what gets called but if you never tackle the problem, it will always persist.

Comment: tbh, I'd probably run a project wide replace to turn `"true"` into `true`.

Comment: `if (condition.toString() === 'true')` should also work and it seems clear enough for me.

Comment: @ChrisG would that I could, but currently we have to follow a more defensive approach.

Comment: Right; so since you're probably using `function tru(val) { ... }` why not pick one approach at random? This question is supremely opinion-based so rather OT.

Comment: @ChrisG I don't think so. The question is not about the best solution to do this check (which is clearly an opinionated question), but only about .includes() and if there is anything to look out for when using it.

Answer (score 2):

`if (condition === true || condition === 'true')` reads as "*Value is `true` or a string that says 'true'*". Which is what you're trying to do. This is just an opinion, but I believe when trying the code readable, it's most important that it *reads* the way it *acts*.

`[true, 'true'].includes(someVariable)` reads as "*this array contains our value*". It is not hard to understand, but it does not come natural to me at all. It's not a piece code typically used for this and may stumble your colleague reading the code for a split second.

Finally, I think that you should ideally make sure to **sanitize the data as soon as possible** and allow the deeper processing code to make some reasonable assumptions about their contents instead of crowding it with tests like the one this question is about. Assumptions are good for both the programmers and for the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

**CPU**

The downside, if any, compared with all the other methods is not worth consideration when the calling rate is low.

However, if the condition is checked at a very high frequency and if every cpu cycle consumed by it makes an impact, I don't think traversing an array to check truthy is the best thing to do.

**Readability**

Should a simple truthy check deserve special attention and thought when a programmer's eyes are traversing a function is another question. There are reasons why spelling mistkaes in this sentence may not be detected at once. These are the same reasons why some familiar statements in the code shouldn't be read fully to understand what goes on.

Comment: "mistkaes" in German, could be translated as "shit-cheese" :-D. Thanks for your answer though!